# recovering overwritten file in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-12.04, data-recovery

I recently just overwrote one of my sql dump file by doing the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -pTucson85719@ Directory > directory.sql
```

is it possible to get back the file that is being overwritten?

Comment: Generally no. With some file systems like ZFS, recovery might be possible.

Comment: WARNING: This has been crossposted to http://superuser.com/questions/802491/recovering-overwritten-file-in-ubuntu-12-0-4  VERY BAD...please do not do this.

Comment: The answer is already in your tags. Restore from backup. Otherwise pay somebody to reconstruct it by manually assembling each sector of the original file, if they didn't get overwritten already. Chances of success are slim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you should enable `noclobber` so this does not happen again. The option will prevent overwriting an existing file with redirection (`>`). To enable it, add the option to your `.bashrc`:

```
$ echo 'set -o noclobber' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now, recovering the fille won't be simple but it is possible that you may still find it in the drive data. If you know some of the text in the file, you could unmount the drive and grep for it:

```
$ sudo grep 'MySQL Data' /dev/sdb2 | strings > recovered.txt
```

Again, you aren't guranteed to find it but I have had some luck with this method in the past. Best of luck to you!

Comment: what do you mean by unmount the disk?

Comment: Unmount is done by `unmount /path/to/device`. If the file is on the same partition as your OS installation, then you need to boot a live rescue CD and do the operation there.

Comment: The problem with this method is that if the file is fragmented, one has to search for the different fragments separately.

Comment: Yup. Not a fun process by any means but, as far as I know, your only shot. It has helped me in the past. But again, I emphasize `noclobber` and proper backups to prevent having to go through the stress of a hail mary.